# Adding fog to scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm adding fog to my scene with three.js (3d visual programming javascript). It's a space scene. The logic is that when the camera moves toward the sun, a yellow mist thickens which creates the illusion that space lights up more the closer you are to the sun. And it's the opposite when you move away from it.  This is essentially having to add two fogs, they both work when I use one or the other, but **never** both at the same time.

I'm trying to create a conditional statement determining which fog to be made active based on the camera's z position, seeing the fog effects are only made visible when the camera is either within a proximity of 1000 (pixels is it?) or beyond that.

This statement only works for Fog condition #1 and not #2. What am I doing wrong here? could this be because the default camera.position.z is already within 1000? Then how can I use the current position and not the default one. Is it even at all doable to have two fogs in a scene?

Thanks.

```
if (camera.position.z < 1000) { 
  /* Fog condition #1:   the farther away, the darker it gets */
  var varColor = 0xffff00;
  var varNear = 800;
  var varFar = 5;
} else if (camera.position.z > 1000) {
  /* Fog condition #2:    the closer to the sun object, the lighter it gets */
  var varColor = 0x000000;
  var varNear = 50;
  var varFar = 7000;
}

scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( varColor, varNear, varFar);
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on here exactly. Are you changing scene.fog upon a camera update, or is your posted code a one-time setup? Note you could also setup the fog once, and then change the parameters (color/near/far) as needed, rather than setting a new THREE.Fog() on each update. Also, have you tried changing the color of the 2nd fog condition to confirm that the issue isn't related to the color? For all intents and purposes, the code you've posted should work.

Comment: The code should work to my mind as well but it simply doesn't. Color isn't the issue, I've checked that. But to your first question, no, this is a one-time setup as you say, I'm going to see about how to change the scene with a camera update. Would you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I figured out the issue. I simply forgot to place the code in the animate function, I had it in the initialization function